# Why long delay (47 secs) to go from camera to AIR on iPad2/iOS6 - CameraUI, Loader, MediaEvent, MediaPromise

Tags: ios, apache-flex, mobile, air, loader

I've had a great deal of success using the DevGirl XpenseIt solution offered by Jason Sturges in response to a couple of other requests for help with this: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11812807/take-photo-using-adobe-builder-flex-for-ios being the best example)

Great success except that between the time you press the 'Use' button in iOS6 after taking a photo using the CameraUI and the util class from the tutorial, it takes fully 47 1-hippopotamus, 2 hippapotamusses until the 'fileReady' event occurs.

It doesn't seem, to my mind that it should take the Loader class that terribly long.

Is there something I can do to improve this performance?  I'm forced to add a hurry-up-and-wait UI element so my users won't think the program has hung.   Here's the code of the CameraUtil.as from the above as I'm currently using it.

```
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11812807/take-photo-using-adobe-builder-flex-for-ios
package classes
{
  import flash.display.BitmapData;
  import flash.display.Loader;
  import flash.display.LoaderInfo;
  import flash.events.Event;
  import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
  import flash.events.IEventDispatcher;
  import flash.events.MediaEvent;
  import flash.filesystem.File;
  import flash.filesystem.FileMode;
  import flash.filesystem.FileStream;
  import flash.media.CameraRoll;
  import flash.media.CameraUI;
  import flash.media.MediaPromise;
  import flash.media.MediaType;
  import flash.utils.ByteArray;

  import mx.graphics.codec.JPEGEncoder;

  import events.CameraEvent;

  [Event(name = "fileReady", type = "events.CameraEvent")]

  public class CameraUtil extends EventDispatcher
  {
    protected var camera:CameraUI;
    protected var loader:Loader;
    public var file:File;

    public function CameraUtil(target:IEventDispatcher=null)
    {
      super(target);

      if (CameraUI.isSupported)
      {
        camera = new CameraUI();
        camera.addEventListener(MediaEvent.COMPLETE, mediaEventComplete);
      }
    } // End CONSTRUCTOR CameraUtil

    public function takePicture():void
    {
      if (camera)
        camera.launch(MediaType.IMAGE);
    } // End FUNCTION takePicture

    protected function mediaEventComplete(event:MediaEvent):void
    {
      var mediaPromise:MediaPromise = event.data;

      if (mediaPromise.file == null)
      {
        // For iOS we need to load with a Loader first
        loader = new Loader();
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderCompleted);
        loader.loadFilePromise(mediaPromise);
        return;
      }
      else
      {
        // Android we can just dispatch the event that it's complete
        file = new File(mediaPromise.file.url);
        dispatchEvent(new CameraEvent(CameraEvent.FILE_READY, file));
      }
    } // End FUNCTION mediaEventComplete

    protected function loaderCompleted(event:Event):void
    {
      var loaderInfo:LoaderInfo = event.target as LoaderInfo;
      if (CameraRoll.supportsAddBitmapData)
      {
        var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(loaderInfo.width, loaderInfo.height);
        bitmapData.draw(loaderInfo.loader);
        file = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("receipt" + new Date().time + ".jpg");
        var stream:FileStream = new FileStream()
        stream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);

        var j:JPEGEncoder = new JPEGEncoder();
        var bytes:ByteArray = j.encode(bitmapData);
        stream.writeBytes(bytes, 0, bytes.bytesAvailable);
        stream.close();
        dispatchEvent(new CameraEvent(CameraEvent.FILE_READY, file));
      }
    } // End FUNCTION loaderComplete

  } // End CLASS CameraUtil
} // End PACKAGE classes
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve my delay problem by removing a step from the process.   This step is one I myself do not need (at the present time) but others may, so removing it is not really an answer to the question of 'why does this process that seems reasonable take what seems an unreasonable amount of time.

I needed the BitmapData, not an external file so instead of:

*Camera => [snap] => Media Promise => Loader => Write File => Event => Read File => Use BitmapData*

I rewrote the class to cut out the File/AppStorage i/o.

*Camera => [snap] => Media Promise => Loader => Use BitmapData*

and so a very reasonable (and expected amount of comp time).

I am still surprised however that it takes such a long time to write the data to a file using the method used in the CameraUtil class.  I do need to write these images out to files, but not until the user has reduced the size to a 1024x768 crop area and I encode them into a very compressed jpg, so hopefully I'll only struggle with a smaller portion of the hang/comp time.

Anybody know... Should it take so very long to write 1 file to application storage in iOS from Adobe AIR (via flex)?

Answer (score 1):

I found this process painstakingly slow, too ...
However, it seems the JPEGEncoder is contributing a lot to this delay.
You can speed up the process a lot using the optimized Encoder that can be found here.

http://www.bytearray.org/?p=775

Depending on your device it is about 2 to 4 times faster than the original one.

Another step that can be omitted is the bitmapData.draw(), which is slow as well, by using the Loader.content directly. This way you skip the instantiation of another bitmap instance, which will blowup memory usage.

Like this:

```
protected function loaderCompleted(event:Event):void
{
  var loader:Loader = (event.target as LoaderInfo).loader;
  var bitmap:Bitmap = loader.content as Bitmap;
  (...)
}
```

Still, I'm waiting for somebody to write an iOS .ane which should be able to encode a jpg in a few ms instead of seconds. But in the meantime... ;)