# How to access ipad camera using flex?

Tags: ios, ipad, apache-flex, flash-builder

My application needs to provide a button to be clicked to turn on the ipad camera and once the picture is taken it should be able to retrieve the picture and show it. I know I can use the CameraRoll  - AS3 class but it just allows me to access the camera roll not the camera itself.

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d49.html

Answer (score 0):

You should find your question answered here by Jason Sturges [ [take photo using Adobe Builder (flex) for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11812807/take-photo-using-adobe-builder-flex-for-ios) ]

He points you to the XpenseIt Tutorial([Flex mobile project FXP download](http://devgirl.org/files/RIAUnleashed/)).  Download the Final .fxp file and add it to your workspace and you'll find good resources to adapt to your needs.

Another resource provided by Adobe Blog contributor Christian Cantrell
http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2011/02/how-to-use-cameraui-in-a-cross-platform-way.html